How does the upper bound on the entropy of the depolarizing channel follow from the concavity of von Neumann entropy?
Let $\sigma_{XA}= \sum_x p_X(x)  \Pi_x \otimes \Phi_A $  where $\Pi_x$ is the projector onto $x$ and $\Phi$ is a pure state. The output state after applying the depolarizing channel $D_p$ is
$$\omega_{XB}= (id \otimes D_p)(\sigma_{XA}) = \sum_x p_X(x) \Pi_x \otimes ((1-p) \Phi + p \tau),$$
where $\tau$ denotes the maximally mixed state.
Consider the output of the completely randomizing channel $\rho_{XB} = \sum_x p_X(x) \Pi_x \otimes \tau_B$.
Now according to eq. 20.111 in Wilde's quantum information theory book by the concavity of the entropy, that is
$$H(\sum_x p_X(x) \rho^x)\geq \sum_x p_X(x) H(\rho^x),$$
it holds that the
$$H(B)_{\omega} =H(Tr_X \omega_{XB})= H(\sum_x p_X(x) ((1-p) \Phi + p \tau)) \leq H(B)_{\rho} = H(Tr_X \rho_{XB})= H(\sum_x p_X(x) \tau) $$
How does one derive the latter upper bound via the concavity of the entropy?

I don't know if there's a typo, but the way you wrote it, don't you just have $\omega_B\equiv\operatorname{tr}X(\omega{XB})=D_p(\Phi_A)$, and thus the inequality amounts to $H((1-p)\Phi+p\tau)\le H(\tau)$. Which must be the case given that $\tau$ has the largest possible entropy, $H(\tau)=\log d$

I see that the upper bound holds for any state, my question is why in Wilde it is said that this holds due to the concavity of the entropy / how to use the concavity of the entropy to derive the upper bound.

gIS is correct; there is no need for the concavity property. In the book, the concavity is used to show that $H(B)w \leq H(B){\rho}$, but not to show that $H(B)_{w} \leq  \log d$

@MonteNero can you explain how to get $H(B){\omega} \leq H(B){\rho} $ by concavity?

@user18722294 I suggest to edit your question and provide definitions of $H(B)w$ and $H(B){\rho}$. As of now, your question has incorrect assumptions and missing definitions.

@MonteNero I edited the assumptions and added the definitions, do you still see any mistakes?
